# How do I access the second element in the nested array of "BLEED_PID"?

Tags: javascript, object, arraylist

I want to get the value 45 from the "BLEED_PID" from ALL the nested arrays. Any help would be appreciated!
I am trying something `await data.map(a => a.BLEED_PID.map(b =>b[1]))` but its not working

```
{
"BLEED_PID": [
[
574.3899962583333,
45
],
[
574.3899962583333,
45
]
],
"VCC_Val": [
[
45.01093534527778,
1.3761732000000002
],
[
190.51661214694445,
31.237473600000005
],
[
321.0463435255555,
28.550190100000005
]
],
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: I want all the second element value i.e 45. Think it would require nested mapping

Comment: @DM Thanks! cleared a bit,but still not there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const data = {
"BLEED_PID": [
[
574.3899962583333,
45
],
[
574.3899962583333,
45
]
],
"VCC_Val": [
[
45.01093534527778,
1.3761732000000002
],
[
190.51661214694445,
31.237473600000005
],
[
321.0463435255555,
28.550190100000005
]
],
}

// data.map(a => a.BLEED_PID.map(b =>b[1]));
console.log(data.BLEED_PID.map(b=>b[1]));
```